# Running XQuery on a text field that's been CAST to XML

Tags: sql-server, xquery, xquery-sql

I'm trying to use XQuery on text data that I've cast to XML, without success.  So this fails:

```
    DECLARE @myDoc TEXT  
    SET @myDoc = '<Root>  
    <ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">  
    <Features>  
      <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>  
      <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>  
    </Features>  
    </ProductDescription>  
    </Root>'  

SELECT CAST(@myDoc AS XML)('(/Root/ProductDescription/@ProductID)[1]', 'int' )
```

but this succeeds:

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml  
DECLARE @ProdID int  
SET @myDoc = '<Root>  
<ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">  
<Features>  
  <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>  
  <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>  
</Features>  
</ProductDescription>  
</Root>'  

SELECT  @myDoc.value('(/Root/ProductDescription/@ProductID)[1]', 'int' )
```

Comment: use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`  not `TEXT`.  And `CAST(@myDoc AS XML).value( . . `

Comment: David Brown is right. After your cast, you need `.value`

Comment: `SELECT CAST(@myDoc AS XML).value('(/Root/ProductDescription/@ProductID)[1]', 'int' )` returns 
Msg 227, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
"VALUE" is not a valid function, property, or field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what David Brown was talking about, this works:

```
DECLARE @myDoc NVARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @ProdID int  
SET @myDoc = '<Root>  
<ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">  
<Features>  
  <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>  
  <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>  
</Features>  
</ProductDescription>  
</Root>'  

SELECT CAST(@myDoc AS XML).value('(/Root/ProductDescription/@ProductID)[1]', 'int' )
```